# Any idea why F6 wouldn't work?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I've a fairly straight forward installation of eclipse. Started with Eclipse for Java EE development, I added the CDT and PyDev (I cannot recall whether <kbd>F6</kbd> was working before adding these extensions).

When debugging, I'm trying to hit the <kbd>F6</kbd> key for step over, and no action takes places.

F5 is working fine. Also, the step over button on the Debug view is working fine. Looking at Preferences -> General -> Keys, <kbd>F6</kbd> is bound is 'Step Over' when Debugging as expected.

Where can I start troubleshooting this issue?

I'm on Windows, Indigo SR 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to bind the key (just to make sure the <kbd>F6</kbd> key on your keyboard really works) but cancel
2. Start Eclipse in a console with the options `-debug -console -consoleLog` Maybe you'll see an error message
3. Try to update PyDev. PyDev had some problematic key bindings in the past which seem to be fixed in 2.4.
4. Check the error log

Comment: Thank you Aaron. It is #1. It is system wide. I opened http://superuser.com/questions/418695/keyboard-f6-doesnt-seem-to-work on superuser.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem, and managed to find another way around.

*Window > Preferences > General > Keys*

Find your debug commands (step over, step into, etc... or just type their hotkeys), select the desired command and click **'Restore Command'**.

Note: I'm using Eclipse Indigo on Fedora 17.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys For each key "F6", "F7", "F8" and "F5" , I restored the command and  changed the When entry from "debugging" to "In Windows". Now all the shorcuts are working.