# Eclipse won't step on F6 on JUnit test from Maven project, will skip entire code

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I am unfamiliar with Maven.

I have set up a simple test case for Spring Web using [their template project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework-issues). I also have imported it into Eclipse using Maven support, and then I successfully get the correct structure, dependencies, etc.

After finishing the code, I tried to debug the test and set a few breakpoints both in the test unit and in my MVC controller.

Unfortunately the result is that I can't step over and follow the code. F6 (Step Over) behaves exactly as F8 (Run) **in this project**. And if I use F5 I can correctly enter the method (despite often those methods do deep into JVM proxying which is not of interest). F7 (Step out) behaves as F8

In every other project, Eclipse works fine.

I don't know what to post here to better describe my situation, I could push the repository to Github but it's not a problem with the code.

I simply created a unit test using `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` and ran it as JUnit unit test from eclipse.

What can I do about it?

Comment: The problem is with the hotkeys or also happens if you click the debugging icons? If clicking the icons works fine try to restore the commands http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382493/any-idea-why-f6-wouldnt-work

Comment: Also with the icons